# Geth installer does not update $PATH, Length too long

Tags: windows, path, installer

When I try to install the latest version of Geth(v1.6.5) on Windows 10 Home, I get the following error:

[image: PATH not updated, original length 1584 > 2024]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I discovered that this error message is from an internal limitation of NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) that they are using for the installer. There is no fix currently.

See: [Issue# 14679](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14679)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue with Geth 1.6.6, so it appears the fix isn't in the latest build.

I followed the instructions here: https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/ to manually add the path where I have Geth to the System Variable 'Path'

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are installing the latest version.  This issue was supposedly fixed last year.

[build/nsis: safe update of PATH #3419 - GitHub](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/3419)